# getline without printing out the input?

Tags: c++, getline

I'm using getline to grab a string to use in my program, but I don't need getline to print out the input user entered. I want it to be like that:

```
server returned: like so
_
```

actual result:

```
like so
server returned: like so
_
```

How do I make getline not to "mirror" the input?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, in my program `std::getline(std::cin, input)` returns an input that user entered

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right, `getline` has nothing to do with displaying the entered text.  But the link identified by ChrisMM shows platform-specific answers for at least 2 platforms.